# AttributeError: '***' object has no attribute '***_set'

Tags: python, django, shell, django-queryset

Would be so happy if anyone could help me.

What I want to do: change all "votes" to zero, after Author has been deleted.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    """Model representing an author."""

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_death = models.DateField('died', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['last_name', 'first_name']

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a particular author instance."""
        return reverse('catalog:author-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return '{0}, {1}'.format(self.last_name, self.first_name)


class Option(models.Model):
    def default_votes():
        d=Author.objects.all().first()
        print(dir(d))
        for a in d.option_set.all():
            a.votes=0
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=default_votes())
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

But I get:

```
  File "C:\Users\chainsaw\Desktop\django-locallibrary-tutorial-master\django-loc
allibrary-tutorial-master\catalog\models.py", line 128, in default_votes
    for a in d.option_set.all():
AttributeError: 'Author' object has no attribute 'option_set'
```

But in the shell there is this attribute. And I can change it. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Also include your code where you get this error.

Comment: Try removing the `()` in `default=default_votes()` and see if that works for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The little problem is that you shouldn't actually **call** your default function; Simply remove the `()`:

```
author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=default_votes)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have set the **`default`** value as **`default=default_votes()`** Since the ***isn't a "callable function"***, Django takes the **result of the function** during migrations file creation.
So, set the default argument to a callable function (provide only function, without paranthesis)

```
author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=default_votes)
```

**Note:** Your function **`default_votes`** isn't return anything, so, return *"appropriate value(s)"* from the function.